# To ToList() or not to ToList()?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, ienumerable

Given an **in memory** (not LINQ to SQL) list of classes:

```
List<MyClass> myItems = /*lots and lots of items*/;
```

which I am grouping using a `GroupBy()` statement:

```
myItems.GroupBy(g => g.Ref)
```

and then immediately consuming in a `foreach` loop is there any difference in calling `.ToList()` on the "group" or should I just use an `IEnumerable`.

So full code examples:

### With `ToList()`

```
List<List<MyClass>> groupedItemsA = new List<List<MyClass>>();
List<List<MyClass>> groupedItemsB = new List<List<MyClass>>();

List<MyClass> myItems = /*lots and lots of items*/;
List<IGrouping<string, MyClass>> groupedItems = myItems.GroupBy(g => g.Ref).ToList();
foreach(IGrouping<string, MyClass> item in groupedItems)
{
  if (/*check something*/)
  {
     groupedItemsA.Add(item.ToList());
  }
  else
  {
    groupedItemsB.Add(item.ToList());
  }
}
```

or

### Using `IEnumerable`

```
List<List<MyClass>> groupedItemsA = new List<List<MyClass>>();
List<List<MyClass>> groupedItemsB = new List<List<MyClass>>();


List<MyClass> myItems = /*lots and lots of items*/;
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyClass>> groupedItems = myItems.GroupBy(g => g.Ref);
foreach(IGrouping<string, MyClass> item in groupedItems)
{
  if (/*check something*/)
  {
     groupedItemsA.Add(item.ToList());
  }
  else
  {
    groupedItemsB.Add(item.ToList());
  }
}
```

Is there any difference in the execution plan of these "under the hood"? Would either of these be more efficient or does it not really matter?

I am **not** using the `groupedItems` list after this.

Comment: Use ToList() when you want to execute the query. Don't use ToList() when your enumerable (and therefore your query) gets extended at a later point in your code (for example by another where condition).

Comment: Why don't you group by the condition in /*check something*/?

Comment: The "check something" is reliant on the grouping.

Comment: I think both your examples have a type an should contain the line `foreach(IGrouping<string, MyClass> item in groupedItems)`

Comment: Yes, cut and paste error @Hogan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is a difference and it can be significant.

`ToList()` will iterate and append each iterated item into a new list. This has the effect of creating a temporary list which consumes memory.

Sometimes you might want to take the memory penalty especially if you intend on iterating the list multiple times and the original list is not in memory.

In your particular example using the `ToList()` you actually end up iterating twice - once to build the list and a second time in your foreach. Depending on the size of the list and your application this may or may not be a concern.

Comment: This is what I thought might be happening. Could you add any references to this to back it up? I struggled to find anything that proved that this is what was happening?

Comment: It's implied behavior of ToList(). It's going to need to force evaluation of the query to build the list - there's no other way around it. See the remarks section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are *sure* you'll use `groupedItems` only *once*, then using `.ToList()` has a single advantage: if there is an exception (for example because your code is doing funny things for calculating `.Ref`) during the grouping, the exception will be in the `.ToList()` row instead of being inside the `foreach`... I don't think it is a big advantage (and perhaps it is a disadvantage).

To clarify:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Ref
    {
        get
        {
            // sometimes I like to throw an exception!
            if (DateTime.Now.Ticks % 10 == 0) throw new Exception();

            return "Foo";
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you have explicitly tagged this question as `IEnumerable`, and in your example `myItems` is a `List<>`, so I won't discuss of the difference of doing `ToList()` or not when you are reading data from a database through Entity Framework/Linq to SQL.

Comment: I'm looking for your comment regarding ToList when using Entity Framework ;)

Comment: @Stefan With ToList() on EF you force the execution of the query at the ToList() point. Everything that is AFTER the ToList() is executed on the .NET side and not on the SQL side.

Comment: on EF, does `Single()` or `First()` executes the query?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, and even ToArray()

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference?

Yes, `.ToList()` creates a new list from iterating the grouped collection:

> [The `ToList<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>)` method forces immediate query evaluation and returns a List that contains the query results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Whether this is noticeable should be benchmarked by you.

If you only iterate the grouped collection once, the `.ToList()` step is unnecessary and will be relatively slower than directly enumerating the `GroupBy()` result.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use the `IEnumerable` rather than the `List()` each time you enumerate it, the `GroupBy` expression would be re-evaluated against your `myItems` List.

This means if you add another item to `myItems` then enumerate it, that item will be included in the `GroupBy` expression.

When you call `ToList` however you create a new List and any changes to `myItems` will not be included in `groupedItems`.