# ToList call after .Skip().Take() is too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm developing an app by use of Angular and ASP.NET and I have problem with loading items. I get data from db with this code:

```
var data = from cs in _context.Cases
           join wp in _context.WantedPersons on cs.ReferenceNumber equals wp.ReferenceNumber
           where cs.Deleted == false && cs.ReferenceNumber != 0
           select new CaseAndWP { Case = cs, WantedPerson = wp };

return await PagedList<CaseAndWP>.CreateAsync(data, caseParams.PageNumber, caseParams.PageSize);
```

Code of Paged list is

```
public PagedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    TotalCount = count;
    PageSize = pageSize;
    CurrentPage = pageNumber;
    TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)PageSize);
    this.AddRange(items);
}

public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var itemss = source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
    // var f = itemss.Count();
    var items = itemss.ToList();
    return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

The problem is `itemss.ToList()` takes too much time and is practically unusable App has currently about 70k rows.

Comment: Why are you doing `source.ToList()...`? That means you need to fetch every record into memory, regardless of which page you're on

Comment: You can find a lot of posts about the wrong usage of `ToList()`. Here is the [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985082/13664939) of them.

Comment: @canton7 sorry pasted wrong code I edited the question

Comment: @gurkan I pasted wrong code, now it is edited. commented var f is 10 as it should be, but toList takes a lot of time and is scaling by pages I select. I do not understand why. It is always 10 items I'm converting tolist where is the problem ?

Comment: Oh, we all make mistakes, it's ok :) For example, what are you sending argument or predicate for `source`?

Comment: Im passing IQueryable that contains approximately 70k Objects of my Type CsAndWP whitch contains two objects of Type case and wantedPerson those contains abou 20 properties mostly string

Comment: @gurkan I just deleted join from query and it works like a charm. But I do not get why

Comment: I think that there are possible multiple reason. First you should eliminate if the problem is in the LINQ query or on the actual database. I assume that you are using SQL db. Did you try the raw query on the SQL? You should review Executing Plan... How is your clustered/non-clustered indexes? These are the first possibilities that come to my mind.

Comment: Missing information: database brand, EF version, generated SQL.

Comment: Define "too much time". Also please specify the time for page 1 vs time for page 10.

Comment: When you did a database trace, what _exact_ query is being submitted to the database?

Comment: @mjwills 0.765 s page 10 2.47  s page 20 4.39s

Comment: @GertArnold EntityFrameworkCore 3.1

Comment: @gurkan raw query is ok

Comment: Just an idea - can add any ordering to your `data` query for example simply by some id? And still it's better to attach generated sql to make it clearer and what database do you use.

Comment: When you did a database trace, what _exact_ query is being submitted to the database?

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` and index scripts for both tables. Also, does adding an `OrderBy` help?

Comment: I finally managed to get to core of the problem. It was  in bad db model. To be exact Reference number in Case was float but int in WantedPerson. After edited case to be int as well it works as it should and all pages are loading under 1s Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

In your title you say ToList call after .Skip().Take() but you've put the ToList() call before, not after.

You need to change this line from this

```
var itemss = source.ToList().Skip((pageNumber-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

to this:

```
var itemss = source.Skip((pageNumber-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Putting ToList() before other IQueryable methods (Skip/Take) will fetch all records from the database and then, query them in memory.

Comment: I'm sorry I pasted wrong code (I tried to call it before just to see if it wont help) and accidentally pasted it in here. I have it like you have said but it is still too slow btw going to edit question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a ToList() there.
Remove it and it should work without any problems.
You can update your method to do the following:

```
 public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, 
            int pageNumber, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber -1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thx for answer but it is still too slow like that. And time is scaling by page what I mean is if I load page 1 I takes about 1s, page 10 6s, page 3000  time out

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get to core of the problem. It was in bad db model. To be exact Reference number in Case was float but int in WantedPerson. After edited case to be int as well it works as it should and all pages are loading under 1s Thank you for help